# Adding constraint on big PostgreSQL table takes too much time

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6. I'm trying to add constraints on a specific table which has 30 millions records and its size is 5G. I'm adding a lot of not null constraints on almost all the columns of the table. I have two questions:

1)What is a better action in aspect of performance :

a.Running the next query for each column :

```
alter table add constraint name check (xxx is not null)
```

b.Adding one constraint check not null for all columns :

```
alter table add constraint name check (xxx is not null, yyy is not null, bbb is not null.....)
```

2)In the first method it takes about 125425 ms to create the constraint on the table when it is empty!. When table is populated with data, it runs for hours and doesn't finish.

Comment: why not `alter table alter column set not null`? not only it should be much faster, it also will be much neater

Comment: It is not much faster as you mentioned :                                               
alter table big_Table ADD CONSTRAINT sys_c008614 CHECK not null; 
duration: 140395.444 ms

alter table big_Table alter column address4_ac set not null;
2017-08-08 14:25:12 IDTreportDBLOG:  duration: 139932.492 ms

Comment: I meant will work faster then a number of check constraints or one contraint with multiple checks, but I changed my mind - I don't know if setting not null will perform better then your design. anyway I dont see benefits in costraints here - you cant add constraint using concurrently prebuilt index here, so why so complicated then?..

Comment: I`m migrating an oracle database to postgresql with ora2pg tool. The tool converted the constraints in oracle and created them in that way. I`m trying  to improve the performance of this system in postgresql because I saw that creating the constraints on that big table takes too much time

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159499/30035 you can save some time for consumers with different level of shares apparently. With your approach. But overall time the operation will take wont be much faster. (but again - users will be able to consume data earlier)

Comment: So if I mention the NOT VALID option the data that is inside the table isnt validated but only inserts and update ?

Comment: yes - existing data validation will be skipped, only new will be validated and thus you have a very short exclusive lock

Comment: So by default when I create a constraint validate is on ?

Comment: yes, by default it check all rows

Comment: I see. OK thanks !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151391/discussion-between-mariel-and-vao-tsun).